# How to reallocate memory for array of structs in C?

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I am a newbie in C. I can't reallocate memory properly. I have a array of structs, I have to to fill it from console.

```
typedef struct net_device {
 char IPv4[16];
 char isOnline[6];
 char *name;
} net_device;

int main () {
struct net_device *net_devicies = NULL;
char *s = NULL;
int count = 0;
int length = sizeof(net_devicies)  / sizeof(net_devicies[0]);
net_devicies = malloc(sizeof * net_devicies * length++);

do {
    printf("Enter a new networ device record: Name, IPv4, isOnline\n");
    s = get_str();
    if (s) {
        char ** res  = NULL;
        char *  p    = strtok (s, " ");
        int n_spaces = 0, i;
        
        while (p) {
            res = realloc (res, sizeof (char*) * ++n_spaces);
            if (res == NULL)
                exit (-1); 
            res[n_spaces-1] = p;
            p = strtok (NULL, " ");
        }

        res = realloc (res, sizeof (char*) * (n_spaces+1));
        res[n_spaces] = 0;
        /// делаем память для имени
        net_devicies[count].name = malloc(strlen(res[0]) + 1);
        strcpy(net_devicies[count].name, res[0]);    
        strcpy(net_devicies[count].IPv4, res[1]);
        strcpy(net_devicies[count].isOnline, res[2]);            
        free(s);
        free(res);
        length++;
        net_devicies = realloc(net_devicies, sizeof(struct net_device) * length);
    }
    
} while (s);

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
     printf ("name = %s; ", net_devicies[i].name);
     printf ("IPv4 = %s; ",  net_devicies[i].IPv4);
     printf ("isOnline = %s; ", net_devicies[i].isOnline);
     printf ("\n");
}
free(net_devicies);
return 0;
```

}

I have problem with this:

```
net_devicies = realloc(net_devicies, sizeof(struct net_device) * length);
```

> Output, when I am adding three users:

```
name = Victor; IPv4 = 172.123.456.898; isOnline = false; 
name = (null); IPv4 = ; isOnline = ; 
name = (null); IPv4 =  isOnline = @Qкv;
```

I just want to increase memory every time, when I am entering new string. How can I do it?

Comment: `sizeof(net_devicies)  / sizeof(net_devicies[0])` will not work as you expect, neither before nor after you allocate memory and actually make `net_devicies` point somewhere valid. The problem is that `net_devicies` is a *pointer*, and the size of a pointer (i.e. `sizeof net_devicies`) will be the size of the pointer itself, not the size of what it might point to.

Answer (score 0):

The `sizeof` issue is the likely reason of your problem.

On a 64-bit system a pointer will typically be 64 bits, 8 bytes. The size of `struct net_device` is much larger than 8 bytes.

That means the value of `length` will be initialized to *zero* (because a small integer value divided by a large integer value is zero).

So

```
net_devicies = malloc(sizeof * net_devicies * length++);
```

is essentially equivalent to

```
net_devicies = malloc(sizeof * net_devicies * 0);
```

You allocate zero bytes! Even if `malloc` returns a non-null pointer (which you really should check for!) you can't dereference that pointer.

Change `length++` to `++length` to solve it, and allocate *one* structure.

Or better yet use `length` (without `++` anywhere) and initialize `length` to `1`:

```
size_t length = 1;
net_devicies = malloc(sizeof *net_devicies * length);
```

---

There are also other problems in your code...

For example `realloc` can fail and then return `NULL`. If this happens the already allocated memory will not be touched, so if you reassign to the same pointer you pass as argument to `realloc` you will have a memory leak. Use temporary variables to hold the result of `realloc`, and check if it's `NULL` or not.

Another problem is that you always have one extra `net_device` structure allocated, and `length` will include this potentially uninitialized structure in the array.

And you don't free all the memory you allocate as you don't free `net_devicies[i].name` (for any *valid* index `i`).